# How do you guys deal with Render Slots?

Tags: rendering, workflow

I have been using the addon "Shift Render Slot" for Blender since I first switched from Cinema 4D in 2017.  (In C4D there are no render slots, you just get a full history of your renders automatically, which I miss terribly, so this addon was the closest I could get to bring that optimization back.).

To my dismay it is now broken in v3.5.  I've written to the developer and he said that due to a core code change the addon can no longer work :(

For those unfamiliar: the addon would automatically advance to the next blank slot whenever you hit render.  Otherwise you have to do this manually, and if you forget you will overwrite the render you just did (which I now do constantly).

Personally, I can't see how the developers ever thought this was a good idea.  I'm so taken back by this that I wonder if maybe I'm missing something, so I wanted to start a conversation and see if you guys could weigh in on your workflows.

Please enlighten me, I would love to hear your best practice when developing a scene and doing a lot of iterative renders, where comparison is paramount to your development process.

Cheers!

Comment: I'd suggest that you ask that question elsewhere as this site is just for answers to problems using Blender, not for discussions about best practices which could lead to long threads. Try https://blenderartists.org/.

Comment: I concede that is a good point, but I am also a member of blenderartists.org and I feel like the users here have a more intellectual style/approach to using the software, so I was hoping that some of them (particularly a few who have weighed in on many of my posts) might take the time to outline their preferred workflows/add-ons/etc. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, the plugin Shift Render Slot is working again.   I'm on Blender 3.6 and it is working as expected.

[Shift Render Slot Add-on](https://blendermarket.com/products/shift-render-slot)

With this add-on, every time you render a still image the render slot is automatically advanced so you don't overwrite your last render.  (There are also a bunch of other features you can explore, but for me this is all I need.)

As you work it is important to be able to look back at all of your renders/iterations to see what's working, measure your progress, etc.

This is absolutely essential to my workflow, and honestly I'm surprised that this is not part of the core functionality of Blender (it is in other 3D apps I will not mention).  But thankfully this plugin exists!